# Query optimization when using a JSON field

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running a PostgreSQL 9.6.4 on my laptop, I have a table called `node` which has a primary key `id` field and a  `properties::jsonb` field.

I have a GIN index setup on the `properties` field.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT   n.*
FROM     node n
WHERE    node_type_id = '2'
AND      properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB
ORDER BY n.id ASC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10;
```

on ~5M rows table it takes about 20 seconds to get an answer. Looking into the explain plan I found out the query optimizer is first sorting the table by the primary key and then filtering by the `properties` field:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..1517.94 rows=10 width=154)
  ->  Index Scan using node_pkey on node n  (cost=0.56..739571.11 rows=4874 width=154)
        Filter: ((properties @> '{"slug": "wild-castles"}'::jsonb) AND ((node_type_id)::text = '2'::text))
```

But when I remove the ordering I'm seeing the optimizer using the index as expected:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM   node n
WHERE  node_type_id = '2'
AND    properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10;

Limit  (cost=93.77..127.10 rows=10 width=154)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on node n  (cost=93.77..16338.56 rows=4874 width=154)
        Recheck Cond: (properties @> '{"slug": "wild-castles"}'::jsonb)
        Filter: ((node_type_id)::text = '2'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on node_ix02  (cost=0.00..92.55 rows=4874 width=0)
              Index Cond: (properties @> '{"slug": "wild-castles"}'::jsonb)
```

Also, a simple `WHERE properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB` behaves as expected:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT   n.*
FROM     node n
WHERE    properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB
;

Bitmap Heap Scan on node n  (cost=93.77..16326.38 rows=4874 width=154)
  Recheck Cond: (properties @> '{"slug": "wild-castles"}'::jsonb)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on node_ix02  (cost=0.00..92.55 rows=4874 width=0)
        Index Cond: (properties @> '{"slug": "wild-castles"}'::jsonb)
```

So I guess I'm wondering why would the optimizer not use the index to filter out the rows first and then order them by the `id` field?

Comment: What are the estimates for a simple `where properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB`?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: What percentage of nodes have a "slug" field? What percentage of those nodes have a "slug" attribute with the value "wild-castles".

Answer (score 1):

Change [Planner Method Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) and force planer not to do seqscan

eg

```
      SET enable_seqscan = OFF;

       SELECT   n.*
        FROM     node n
               WHERE    node_type_id = '2'
               AND      properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB
             ORDER BY n.id ASC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you sometimes have to trick the query planner to get it to perform well, and it takes some tweaking and fiddling with...

I would try running this to see how it performs:

```
SELECT nn.* FROM (
    SELECT n.*
    FROM   node n
    WHERE  node_type_id = '2'
    AND    properties @> '{"slug":"wild-castles"}'::JSONB
) nn
ORDER BY nn.id ASC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10;
```